# regular expression for converting underscores to dash in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to convert an underscore to dash in php.

hi i have a regular expression that converts white spaces to dash but how can i achieve underscore to dash?

```
 $item = preg_replace('/\ +/', '-', $item);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression. Use [`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

`$item = str_replace('_', '-', $item);`

Comment: Or better yet, strtr(), because it's faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_replace('/_/', '-', $item);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both space and underscore to dash with one regex:

```
$item = preg_replace('/[ _]+/', '-', $item);
```